# How to prove the tautology ¬(P↔¬P) using Fitch?

Tags: logic, proof

Just as the question proposes, I'm having trouble with proving this tautology. I know one should use proof by contradiction however I am currently stuck.

Comment: Assume **(P↔¬P)** and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Second step: unpack **P↔¬P** with **↔**-elimination rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the Fitch software:

[image]